# Installing Python OpenCV with Precompiled Framework

Tags: python, macos, frameworks, opencv

I got the pre-compiled framework of OpenCV 2.0 for Mac, and it works great, but it didn't come with the python bindings. How can I now install the python bindings for OpenCV?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I got the framework here: http://vislab.cs.vt.edu/~vislab/wiki/images/4/44/OpenCV2.0.dmg I found that link here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easieste method I find to install opencv is with homebrew

```
brew install opencv
```

it will install all the libraries and dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try http://thepetitegeek.blogspot.com/2009/09/installing-opencv-on-mac-os-x-with.html
The version is pretty old, but the process might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pre-compiled framework, you'll be on the safe side using something like [source-based](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/MacosxInstallGuide) framework using the source, MacPorts or HomeBrew. It comes with the python bindings.

Comment: in fact the link pointed to  the 3 different ways: src, macports, and homebrew (as answered by @fabrizioM). so apparently it worked out finally!